# Warning: date() [function.date]:

Tags: php, datetime, date

Does anyone know where I can read the documentation for the solution to this warning. I can search for the warning and I just get a phonebook worth of pages that have the same problem.

> Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.

```
 $config['today'] = date('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: can you post the current code you have so that the rest of us can understand the situation better?

Comment: Seems to me where ever that line of code shows up I get the warning. It is in several places in my pages for people filling in forms and such. Very simple pages, nothing complex is going on.

Comment: No wonder! I am scrounging through all the code trying to figure out what I had changed in error and it is the product of a different php config on a server! Ugh! Thank you all, I really appreciate it. Someday I will be able to answer some of the questions on the site I swear!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it is because you do not have default time zone set in php.ini.
Add this line at the beginning of your PHP.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

p.s. of course, change to your time zone.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the default timezone for PHP in either the `php.ini` file or in your programs entry point file.

See more information at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone.

Answer (score 0):

The method, as mentioned by Nathan, can be fixed by setting the timezone, as mentioned at:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

The warning, identical to your post, is mentioned on this page at:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php#73174

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this post, I was wonder why my PHP timezone always set to GMT +0, and not following my machine timezone, this is the reason.

I just run a test,date_default_timezone_set() only affected date(), but not time()